# Utility to save current selection or clipboard to a file

Tags: macos, copy-paste

Is there a utility that saves current selection (from terminal, web browser, ...) to a text/html file in a specific location?

I want to use it as a quick note taking tool so I do not have to "create new file, paste, save file" each time I want to take some note.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open Automator and create a service "text2file" with the following steps:

[image]

After saving the service, you may choose any text (you don't have to copy it!) and in the context menu -> Services choose "text2file" to save the content to clip.txt on your desktop.

After saving the file you can add a shortcut for "text2file" in System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Services -> Text -> text2file

The screenshot above is taken in Automator 2.2.4/10.7 (Lion). If another system is used the steps might be slightly different.

Comment: I get this error "text2file" service could not be used!

Comment: I don't know what was the problem but after restarting my Mac it now works perfectly. I also needed to change the script to auto-generate the filename. Will write about it on my next weblog post.

Answer (score 1):

Create a shell script `clip2file` (or function) in `bash`:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

pbpaste -pboard general -Prefer txt > ${1:-~/clip.txt}
```

and run it with

```bash
clip2file ~/Desktop/clip.txt
```

to save the current clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

TextEdit has the Service "New TextEdit Window Containing Selection" & [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/) adds the Service "New TextWrangler Document with Selection" to the right click menu.

You could add a key command to either from System Prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Services
...though it wouldn't auto-save for you, it might be a start.